# Asynchronous calls from C++ into COM component imported via TLB

Tags: c++, asynchronous, com, typelib

I have an `#import`ed external component that provides methods that are rather expensive to call (typical execution takes from a few seconds to several minutes). So far, I've been calling the component from a separate worker thread, but I find myself implementing more and more of the original interface in the communication protocol between UI and worker, which I'd rather avoid due to code duplication.

In another project, I have used [asynchronous method calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301334.aspx) to handle this, however this time I haven't defined the interface, so I cannot set an `[async_uuid]` attribute on it.

Is there a way to reuse the interface definition in the TLB to make asynchronous calls into an external component?

Comment: Won't help if the COM component is STA. All asynchronous calls will be queud

Comment: That is completely acceptable. The current implementation is a hand-coded asynchronous variant of those parts I've used from the existing interface. As the MIDL compiler can generate asynchronous interfaces automatically if told, I wonder if I could use that to reduce the effort and avoid errors.